# Bearer token not working in requests.post authorization header?

Tags: python, python-requests, bearer-token

I'm having a problem sending an authorization token with Bearer to an API via python requests.post:

```
token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZjNGE5NDBjNWE5ODE5MGJlNzIwYjI0ZDY2MTMzZWVmIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NzY4MjU0NzgsImV4cCI6MTU3NjgyOTA3OCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0MDQwIiwiYXVkIjpbImh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDA0MC9yZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJwYXJjZWxfc3RvcmFnZSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJwcy5tLmNsaWVudCIsInN1YiI6ImI0ZjVmNmVjLWEyMDItNDhjZC1hZmVjLTA4ZDc3OGJmNzYzNyIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU3NjgyNTQ3OCwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InZlc3RhIiwic2NvcGUiOlsib3BlbmlkIiwicHJvZmlsZSIsInBhcmNlbF9zdG9yYWdlIiwib2ZmbGluZV9hY2Nlc3MiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.araPfT_HS0iMXUWS0KcSq3fvowJpu9ONtNsENUtZuk7lV3vxSpyNhUULdZSFdQdZs5830afxRC9qapzYNzDI48ALDrlconKDwReaG9QQhJ61p9dTbSskJDTReGDYwRxEgmZBhjOFD_KeVklbKWevXTGQ2dW3nzGtJ26uMFrSpOww4yNBvJ9Daafson-tZNXeG6xZ09H5GHY43Qp9P25kNRBfeFyKzYuF7xoygk_TQSlMike2Fzjec9TBbudSsTP62qIAXkYckvGF5fI5buJWsw5tvrDtgKVSfVs_SD27-3MIjde27fG89sH-CUYryroy6YiHyTx6UOYTvC2dBNzm5A"

test_url = 'https://fpt.titec.ir/api/v1/parcel/getprecode'
header = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token),
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
data = {'serviceTypeId': '2'}
response = requests.post(test_url, data=data, headers=header)
```

But every time the response returned 401 status code.
In postman it works well but in python code it doesn't work. Is it a bug in requests.post?
By the way the token expires in 60 min.

Is there anyone who could help me please?

I can do this successfully with requests.get for another url that needs exactly the same token!!

Comment: Have you tried with a different token?

Comment: @Joe The generator of This token and the API has the same owner. so the generator API is working well. and the APIs with the "get" method is working well too. but "post" method does not work properly with the python code. calling this APIs with postman is ok but with requests.post is not working.